# mui datetimepicker not working inside shadcn ui drawer component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

datetimepicker dialog does not focus after placing it inside shadcn ui drawer component

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <Drawer>
    <DrawerTrigger asChild>
      <Button variant={"outline"}>Reservation</Button>
    </DrawerTrigger>
    <DrawerContent>
      <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-sm">
      <form className="relative" onSubmit={handleReservation}>
  <DrawerHeader>
    <DrawerTitle className="text-center text-xl">
      Table Reservation
    </DrawerTitle>
    <DrawerDescription className="text-center text-sm">
     our Staff
      will get back to you Asap.
    </DrawerDescription>
  </DrawerHeader>
  <div className="p-4 pb-0 space-y-2">
    <div className="space-y-2">
      <Input
        required
        type="name"
        placeholder="Name"
        minLength={2}
        className="text-gray-500"
      />
      <Input
        required
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        className="text-gray-500"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="p-4 pb-0">
      <div className="text-[0.70rem] uppercase text-muted-foreground">
        Pick No. of People
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center space-x-2">
        <NumberOfPersons people={people} setPeople={setPeople} />
      </div>
    </div>
       <DemoContainer components={["DateTimePicker"]}>
  <DateTimePicker
    label="Pick Date & Time"
    value={dateValue}
    //className={classes.dateInput}
    className="myDatePicker"
    onChange={handleDateChange}
  
  />
</DemoContainer>
    <Textarea
      value={message}
      onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      minLength={5}
      maxLength={400}
      placeholder="Type your special request here."
    />
  </div>
  <DrawerFooter>
    <Button className="bg-blue-900 hover:bg-blue-600" type="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
    <DrawerClose asChild>
      <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
    </DrawerClose>
  </DrawerFooter>
</form>
      </div>
    </DrawerContent>
  </Drawer>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

getting this error inside my browser console

function $d3863c46a17e8a28$var$focus(element, {select: select=false}={}) {

> only focus if that element is focusable
> if (element && element.focus) {
> const previouslyFocusedElement = document.activeElement;
> NOTE: we prevent scrolling on focus, to minimize jarring transitions for users
> element.focus({
> preventScroll: true
> });
> only select if its not the same element, it supports selection and we need to select
> if (element !== previouslyFocusedElement && $d3863c46a17e8a28$var$isSelectableInput(element) && select)
> element.select();
> }